# Drag glitch in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, xml-visualizer

I know this glitch is just visual, but it can get disturbing. So i made a relative layout holding a buttons. I wanted to use the XML visualizer, but when I ***drag around*** the relative layout, it redraws a lot and makes it so theirs many picture of the layout. Actually, it dose that for all my layouts! (The bigger ones are less noticeable) **Note that this stops as soon as I stop dragging.**

Here is a screen shot:
[image: Drag Glitch]

This happens most of the time when I use the xml editor. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just In case someone is experience such things, this has been patched in the latest android studio version.